# Repeating a for in line loop python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, csv, repeat

How would I repeat this (excluding the opening of the file and the setting of the variables)?
this is my code in python3

```
file = ('file.csv','r')
 count = 0 #counts number of times i was equal to 1
 i = 0 #column number 
 for line in file:
    line = line.split(",")     
    if line[i] == 1:
        count = count + 1
 i = i+1
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]", and then [edit] your question so it's clear what you're asking.  Show us what you've tried, what your code did, and what you wanted it to do instead.  As you can tell from the shot-in-the-dark answers below, no one knows what you're _actually asking_.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, try this and adjust for however you want to format. Replace `NUM_COLUMNS` with the number of times you want it repeating

```
file = open('file.csv','r')
data = file.readlines()
for i in range(NUM_COLUMNS): 
    count = 0
    for line in data:
        line = line.split(",")

        if line[i] == ("1"):
            count = count + 1
    print count
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return the number of fields in the csv file `file_name` whose value is `field_value`, which is what I think you are trying to do:

```
import csv

def get_count(file_name, field_value):
    count = 0 
    with open(file_name) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            count += row.count(field_value)
    return count

print(get_count('file.csv', '1'))
```